# SQL Looping

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I'm building this report in a system for a Billboard company.
They have a table that stores all their billboards, and among other data, billboards have a Start Date and a Finish Date (both can be null).
If for some reason a billboard has to stop beeing used, they set a finish date and it will become unnavaiable to be used after that date. Same with Start date (in case they just set up a new board and it will be avaiable for use after a set Start Date).

In this report I have to get the sum of all possible advertising spots in a given period of time.

So, lets say that for the period I chose (4 weeks, for exemple)
    * In week 1 there are 500 avaiable boards
    * In week 2 one board became unavaiable (making 498 boards avaiable)
    * In week 3 two boards became avaiable (making 501 boards avaiable)
    * In week 4 one board became avaiable and one other became unavaiable (making 501 boards avaiable)

So then I should have a total of 1990 avaiable boards in this period, that's the result I'm after.

How can I get this in a single query?
The weeks will come from a HTML form and I have to convert them to dates before the query, so I'll just have the dates I want to know how many boards are avaiable at.
The query to get the amount of boards for ONE specific date is like this:

```
SELECT  
  COUNT(IdBillboard)  
FROM  
  tBillboards  
WHERE  
  (StartDate IS NULL OR StartDate <= '2009-01-05 00:00:00')  
  AND (FinishDate IS NULL OR FinishDate >= '2009-01-05 00:00:00')
```

I can't just add `AND` and `OR` conditionals for each date because I kinda need a new recount for the separate dates. I thought about using a `WHILE` but couldn't figure out exactly how to do it for this case. So that's where I'm stuck...
I'll post more details if anyone needs them.

Thanks, Gabe

Comment: I think you meant 498 boards in week 2.

Comment: Is everything always delimited by week?

Comment: @JPunyon the start and finish dates aren't delimited by week. But the dates I'll use as parameters are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if this is what you're looking for, but could be a step in the right direction.

```
SELECT  
  SUM(CASE WHEN 
   (StartDate IS NULL OR StartDate <= '2009-01-05 00:00:00')  
      AND (FinishDate IS NULL OR FinishDate >= '2009-01-05 00:00:00')
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END)) Week1Count,
  SUM(CASE WHEN 
   (StartDate IS NULL OR StartDate <= '2009-01-12 00:00:00')  
      AND (FinishDate IS NULL OR FinishDate >= '2009-01-12 00:00:00')
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0 END)) Week2Count
FROM  
  tBillboards
```

Comment: Thanks, Barry! I hadn't even thought about putting the results in different columns. But it still isn't perfect. The grouping fucntions should be SUM instead of COUNT, and after that, the where clause isn't even relevant. If you edit it so I can check as accepted, I'll be more than glad doing it

Comment: Yeah I kinda rushed the answer. Edited now.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an answer to your question, but you should consider using `BETWEEN` instead of the `AND`s.

```
WHERE  
  (StartDate IS NULL) OR 
  StartDate BETWEEN '2009-01-05' AND '2009-01-05'
```

IMO this is much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the dates from the form into a (possibly temporary) table then your query can be:

```
SELECT  
  COUNT(t.IdBillboard)  
FROM  
  tBillboards r, tDates d
WHERE  
  (t.StartDate IS NULL OR StartDate <= d.date)  
  AND (t.FinishDate IS NULL OR FinishDate >= d.date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
    SELECT DATEADD(ww, num, @initdate) AS wd
    FROM (
        SELECT 0 AS num
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3
        ) w
    ) weeks, Billboards bb
WHERE wd BETWEEN NULLIF(bb.StartDate, wd) AND NULLIF(bb.EndDate, wd)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no WHILE in SQL. To loop, you join to another table.

You don't specify it but I suppose that billboards change availability on one day of the week, say Sunday, and they can't change multiple times per week.

What you need to do is to create a table of all possible weeks when this change can happen, let's call it DT for date, with a single date column x that has one date per week (Sunday?).

Then do something like this:

```
select count(*) from tBillboards b
inner join DT d
    on (b.startdate is null or b.startdate <= d.x)
       and (b.finishdate is null or b.finishdate < d.x)
where d.x between period_start and period_end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using SQL Server 2005 or later, you can do this using a CTE as in the following example.  In my example you need to set a date and the number of weeks that you wish to look back from this date:

```
DECLARE @dtNow DATETIME
DECLARE @iNumberOfWeeks INT
SET @dtNow = '2009-01-21'
SET @iNumberOfWeeks = 2;


WITH CountForPeriod (IdBillBoard, StartDate, FinishDate, NumberOfWeeksBack) AS
(
    SELECT IdBillBoard, StartDate, FinishDate, 1 AS NumberOfWeeksBack
    FROM tBillBoards
    WHERE (StartDate <= @dtNow)
    AND (FinishDate >= @dtNow)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT b.IdBillBoard, b.StartDate, b.FinishDate, 1 + NumberOfWeeksBack
    FROM tBillBoards b
    JOIN CountForPeriod c
    ON (b.StartDate <= DATEADD(dd, -7 * c.NumberOfWeeksBack, @dtNow))
    AND (b.FinishDate >= DATEADD(dd, -7 * c.NumberOfWeeksBack, @dtNow))
)
SELECT NumberOfWeeksBack, COUNT(*)
FROM CountForPeriod
WHERE NumberOfWeeksBack <= @iNumberOfWeeks
GROUP BY NumberOfWeeksBack
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the total for the first 4 weeks in 2009. To check for another year, change the two occurrences of 2009 in the query below to the year you are interested in.

```
select sum(Count) as Total
from (
    SELECT w.Week, Count(*) as Count
    FROM tBillboards b
    inner join (
        select 1 as Week
        union all
        select 2
        union all
        select 3
        union all
        select 4
    ) w on StartDate is null or datepart(ww, StartDate) <= w.Week
        and FinishDate is null or datepart(ww, FinishDate) >= w.Week
    where isnull(year(StartDate), 2009) <= 2009
        and isnull(year(FinishDate), 2009) >= 2009
    group by w.Week
) a
```

If you need more than the first 4 weeks, continue to add numbers to the inner query with the UNIONs in it.